# Magento custom menu on product view

Tags: magento

I'm creating a custom menu instead of a top.menu.
In `new-top-menu.phtml` I show all product categories. In a StaticBlock I add this phtml template file

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/new-top-menu.phtml"}}
```

In `page.xml` file in section

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
```

I add this new line

```
<block type="cms/block" name="top-menu">
    <action method="setBlockId">
        <block_id>top-menu</block_id>
    </action>
</block>
```

In `header.phtml` I replace this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

with this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top-menu')  ?>
```

The menu works fine, but when I'm go into product view. I'm get error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Trace:
#0 /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#4 /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#5 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(943): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(141): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('top-menu', true)
#14 /app/design/frontend/default/przewody/template/page/html/header.phtml(51): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('top-menu')
#15 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/sites/...')
#16 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#17 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#21 /app/design/frontend/default/przewody/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#22 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/sites/...')
#23 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#24 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#30 /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#31 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#32 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#33 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you've made a custom menu which needs to be displayed on all pages.

You can do this by adding the block in the right place in your layout files. For this, you don't need to use a static block.

In your own theme, you have to add the following to your `local.xml` layout file:

```
<default>
  <reference name="header">
     <block type="catalog/product_list" name="top-menu" 
            template="catalog/new-top-menu.phtml" />
  </reference>
</default>
```

Make sure that `catalog/new-top-menu.phtml` is added to your theme. And a copy of `header.phtml` in your theme, should be updated as described in your question.

This will show your custom menu in the header of all pages. As you can see, you don't need a static block to accomplish this. Unless, there is another reason you are using a static block?

Comment: Better to add the new template file to `base/default` theme.